Obtain approved date and corresponding revision no from a table containing merged data and display as output
enter image description here
The first image is the input wherein multiple drawing IDs will be added to the end and they will also be revised later on. The output should look like this, where in the Approved Dates should look like this and depending on whenever a new Drawing ID is entered in the original sheet or new versions are approved, it should get automatically added and the status changed. Anyone know how to do that? enter image description here
I used a VBA code to unmerge Drawing No and Description, I also concatenated it. I don't know how to place the approved date in the way I require for the output nor show the status.

Is this Excel with VBA? If so you should include both of those tags (more important than those you have used) so your question will be noticed by people looking for those types of questions
